# How to get value in the href attribute and use in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery + ajax code to tracking click for ad links on my website. This is for testing purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".myadlinks").on("click",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var d = {id:$(this).attr('id')};
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : "adlinktracking.php",
    data : d,
    success : function(responseText){
        if(responseText==1){
            alert('click is saved OK');
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        }else if(responseText==0){
            alert('click can't be saved.');
        }
        else{
            alert('error with your php code');
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

When I click on an ad link, it show the alert: Click is saved OK but then It won't redirect to the expected url. I think there is something wrong with this line of code `window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');`. Because When i tried to replace `$(this).attr('href');` with "http://www.google.com". It works.

Please help... many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` not points to the link in the context of success callback. you have to set it in seprate variable and use it in success callback. check the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myadlinks").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var currentobj = this;
        var d = {id:$(this).attr('id')};
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : "adlinktracking.php",
            data : d,
            success : function(responseText){
                if(responseText==1){
                    alert('click is saved OK');
                    window.location.href = $(currentobj).attr('href');
                }else if(responseText==0){
                    alert('click can't be saved.');
                }
                else{
                    alert('error with your php code');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a reference to the `href` attribute not in the callback. `$(this)` in the call back is not the link a user has clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myadlinks").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        var linkHref = link.attr('href'); //this line is new
        var d = {id: link.attr('id')};

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : "adlinktracking.php",
            data : d,
            success : function(responseText){
                if(responseText==1){
                    alert('click is saved OK');
                    window.location.href = linkHref; //reference to the save href
                } else if(responseText==0){
                    alert('click can't be saved.');
                } else{
                    alert('error with your php code');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please be more specific, how to reference that in my case?

Comment: window.location.href = $(".myadlinks").attr('href');
but there has to be only one class myadlinks otherwise use id.
Or you can pass the href at the begining of .click function like :
  $(".myadlinks").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        ....
        window.location.href = link;